# Getting a Ruby 3.x argument error on a proc line in an rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to convert a Ruby 2.7 application to Ruby 3.0.4 . This app is running Rails 6.1.7 and rspec 5.1.2. I have a CommonIssue model with a has many relationship to Issue. I am getting

```
#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)>
```

from the following line

```
proc { CommonIssue.first.issues << Issue.first }
  .should raise_error("Validation failed: Issue has already been taken")
```

The following form of this also gives me the same error

```
expect { CommonIssue.first.issues << Issue.first }
  .to raise_error("Validation failed: Issue has already been taken")
```

I don't see 2 arguments for any of this. What about the first line of code above throws this error? I believe the "should" line is okay it's the one above it.

Stack trace:

```
Failure/Error:
   proc { CommonIssue.first.issues << Issue.first }
     .should raise_error("Validation failed: Issue has already been taken")
 
   expected Exception with "Validation failed: Issue has already been taken", got #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)> with backtrace:
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/i18n-1.12.0/lib/i18n.rb:210:in `translate'
     # ./config/initializers/dynamic_form_monkey_patch.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in full_messages'
     # ./config/initializers/dynamic_form_monkey_patch.rb:47:in `each'
     # ./config/initializers/dynamic_form_monkey_patch.rb:47:in `block in full_messages'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activemodel-6.1.7/lib/active_model/errors.rb:237:in `each'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activemodel-6.1.7/lib/active_model/errors.rb:237:in `each'
     # ./config/initializers/dynamic_form_monkey_patch.rb:34:in `full_messages'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:21:in `initialize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `new'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `raise_validation_error'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/validations.rb:53:in `save!'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:302:in `block in save!'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:354:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:350:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:302:in `save!'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:48:in `save!'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:80:in `save_through_record'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:31:in `insert_record'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:437:in `block (2 levels) in concat_records'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:462:in `replace_on_target'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:283:in `add_to_target'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:435:in `block in concat_records'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:433:in `each'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:433:in `concat_records'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:130:in `concat_records'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:40:in `concat_records'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:121:in `block in concat'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:136:in `block in transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `block in transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.7/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:320:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:135:in `transaction'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:121:in `concat'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:21:in `concat'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:1027:in `<<'
     # ./spec/models/common_issue_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/common_issue_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:76:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/strategy.rb:30:in `cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/cleaners.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/cleaners.rb:35:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.18.1/lib/webmock/rspec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/common_issue_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:76:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/strategy.rb:30:in `cleaning'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/cleaners.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-core-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner/cleaners.rb:35:in `cleaning'
 # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webmock-3.18.1/lib/webmock/rspec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: You have a stacktrace, presumably?

Comment: It appears your issue is going to be here:  "./config/initializers/dynamic_form_monkey_patch.rb". See [Here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/)

Comment: I think you might be right. That file calls I18n.translate which requires keyword args now.

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out the monkey patch file in the stack trace was the real issue here. In particular it uses the I18n translate function which requires keyword arguments. I was able to fix this issue by rewriting the monkey patch which was apparently designed to run messages from models through I18n translate based on this info.
[https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dynamic_form/1.1.4/ActiveModel/Errors][1]

However rewriting this patch to eliminate the error brought another error.

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/i18n-1.12.0/lib/i18n.rb:57:in `config': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Not my call but the more I work with this the more I want to ask that it not be used because it's more trouble than it's worth.